# Docker build not using layer cache

Tags: scala, docker, caching, dockerfile

**Given**: I want to build a Dockerfile to compile a Scala application. To speedup the build I want the dependency download to be cached.

**Problem**: The command `./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy update` is not cached for some reason.

```
FROM openjdk:8 as workspace

ARG BUILD_VERSION

WORKDIR /build

COPY ./sbt ./sbt
COPY ./sbt-dist ./sbt-dist
COPY ./build.sbt ./build.sbt
COPY ./project/build.properties ./project/build.properties
COPY ./project/plugins.sbt ./project/plugins.sbt

RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy update

COPY ./ ./

# Embedded postgres need to be run as non-root user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash runner
RUN chown -R runner /build
USER runner

RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy clean test
RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy docker:stage -Ddocker.image.version="${BUILD_VERSION}"
```

Because this build runs in a new VM all the time I push the workspace image and pull it on the next run to build the cache from it

```
docker build --rm=false --cache-from=workspace --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=1 -t workspace .
```

Here is a piece of the output

```
Step 2/22 : ARG BUILD_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de98ffcfad8e
Step 3/22 : WORKDIR /build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 253b71142240
Step 4/22 : COPY ./sbt ./sbt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3091fa1e1821
Step 5/22 : COPY ./sbt-dist ./sbt-dist
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f9c68659cd91
Step 6/22 : COPY ./build.sbt ./build.sbt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d30058c451fc
Step 7/22 : COPY ./project/build.properties ./project/build.properties
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7451eb63303f
Step 8/22 : COPY ./project/plugins.sbt ./project/plugins.sbt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 79ac2d1e5ff5
Step 9/22 : RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy update
 ---> Running in 609104e7045e
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.0.3 ...
```

Can anyone explain me why Docker is not using the cache here?
A link to a explanation how the cache really decides when to use the cache would be ok as well. As far as I know here Docker should use the cache until the signature of the RUN command changes.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer by the way :) The Dockerfile itself was ok except one problem I could then find via `docker history` Which shows the real shell command which are executed by docker.

The Problem was that `ARG BUILD_VERSION` lead to docker adds to every run command the environment variable like `/bin/sh -c "ARG=123 ./sbt ..."`. This leads to a different call signature and a different hash every time the arg changes and therefore the run command is not applied from cache. To fix this issue just move the `ARG` down to the first `RUN` command which needs it.

```
FROM openjdk:8 as workspace

WORKDIR /build

COPY ./sbt ./sbt
COPY ./sbt-dist ./sbt-dist
COPY ./build.sbt ./build.sbt
COPY ./project/build.properties ./project/build.properties
COPY ./project/plugins.sbt ./project/plugins.sbt

RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy update

COPY ./ ./

# Embedded postgres need to be run as non-root user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash runner
RUN chown -R runner /build
USER runner

RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy clean test

ARG BUILD_VERSION
RUN ./sbt -sbt-dir ./sbt-dir -ivy ./ivy docker:stage -Ddocker.image.version="${BUILD_VERSION}"
```

Comment: I really wish there was some way to show or log why it was using the cache or not. I have gotten very adept at preventing caching when I need it to be prevented, but I often want it to cache for performance and I know nothing has changed in step that stops caching but it doesn't cache. I do make sure to have the ARG commands as late as I can - at the end or right before it needs it.

Answer (score 0):

As the docker build output shows, the building stopped using the cache at the stage:

```
4:32:35 PMStep 4/22 : ADD ./sbt ./sbt
4:32:36 PM---> 7a9e21819cea
```

This is happening because there have been changes in the `./sbt` folder on the host and thus docker will rerun the `ADD` instruction. From there on, docker will not use the cache anymore as a base layer was invalidated causing the layers after it to also be invalidated.

The change might be in the contents of the directories, but rather something trivial such as a timestamp.

As a best practice, to get advantage of the build caching mechanism, you should delay instructions that change often to the bottom of the Dockerfile. In general, adding source to a docker image is one of these steps that changes the very frequently between builds.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong log output. Please have a look again